# volume of right Parallelepiped

Tags: geometry

in a 3 day i have a national exam so i am trying to work hard  i have one question from this link

```
http://www.naec.ge/images/doc/EXAMS/exams-2011-gat-5-ivlisi-.pdf
```

see problem 76.  because it is written into Georgian i will translate it right now, problem is  following:as you see right   Parallelepiped which has dimension `width=10cm` and `height=6cm` is divided into 6 equal right  Parallelepiped,we are asked to find volume of each one,sure one of the very simple method is find length   calculate volume of original and then divide by 6  i think that  for original  Parallelepiped,width=10,height=6,and length=10  from figure it seems that base is regular ,so  volume of each  will be 100cm^3 but i am not sure please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since all of them are identical, from the image you can conclude that the height of each parallelepiped is $\frac{6}{3}=2$ and the width is $10$ and depth $\frac{10}{2}=5$. Hence the volume of each parallelepiped will be $2\cdot10\cdot5=100$ cm$^3$.

Comment: aa yes i see answer is same but   i had wrong way ok thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

You were right to conclude that the full parallelepiped is $10 \times 10\times 6$.  It follows from that, exactly as you wrote, that each piece has volume $100$ cm$^3$.
You did not have the "wrong way", you had another right way.

So your academic year is about over?  Over the last few months, I have enjoyed trying to figure out problems in Georgian that you did not translate.